Mapping from Domain Object to JPA Entity: How to properly fetch associated entity?
I am following DDD in my application and I want to separate my persistence layer from domain layer.
I have to map the Domain objects to JPA entities for persistence.
I have one Domain aggregate named Employee having positionId as an attribute. In the persistence layer I have both EmployeeEntity and PositionEntity marked with JPA @Entity annotation as below:
@Entity
public class EmployeeEntity {
  @Id
  private String employeeId;

  //other properties
  
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "position_id")
  private PositionEntity position;
}

@Entity
public class PositionEntity {
  @Id
  private String position_id;
   
  //other properties
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "position")
  private EmployeeEntity employee;

}

public class EmployeeDataAccessMapper {

    public EmployeeEntity employeeToEmployeeEntity(Employee employee) {

      return EmployeeEntity.builder().
              //get and set all properties
             .build();
    } 
}

My question is:

How to approach mapping from Employee to EmployeeEntity ?

Option A: Do I first fetch the PositionEntity from the database to satisfy its relationship with EmployeeEntity? In that case PositionJpaRepository will be required from within the mapper class.
Option B: Only having positionId in the EmployeeEntity and no need to receive the entire PositionEntity.
2.  If I choose Option A, will it affect performance of my application ?

I think there is no good answer in your question, it depends on what you need to do with fetched data. If you only need the positionId  so you don't need to fetch every thing. You can create 2 mappers, one for each case. And do not forget that by default @OneToOne loads child entities eagerly

As suggested by @akuma8, it depends on what you need to do with the Employee data, both on returning it in the REST response and in getting it in a POST or other call that may save or update the entity in the database.
In case you choose to use the full Position (i.e. the domain object for PositionEntity) in the Employee class, on data reading you will have always the mapper to fully convert the entity in the domain counterpart, and this data will always be transferred to the client, even if this may not be interested in the position information. While in data writing, the caller has to give back the position (or, at least, its id) in the body of the request. In this case, you may think about adding some CASCADE logic to the entities.
Instead, choosing to manage the attribute just using the id in the domain object, the full information won't be always returned (even if it will always be fetched from the database, unless you choose a lazy loading instead of an eager one), and you can use the JpaRepository's getReferenceById method to populate the entity's position attribute accordingly without any further calls to the db (unlike it happens when calling the findById).
Of course, in this case you will need an additional endpoint to let the client get and update Position information, given its id, and this may add some overhead.
Specifically for this case, since there is a @OneToOne relation, so that the two objects are logically coupled and if it won't happen that the position id may change to another record as it would happen in a @ManyToOne relation for example, the complete mapping (so, the Option A), could be the best one.
